# WinAPI mouse move notification for full desktop

Tags: c, winapi

In WinAPI is there a mouse move notification for the full desktop (full screen) and not for a window only?

I would like to receive mouse screen coordinates in my main window procedure.

**Edit:**

What I try to do is getting the coordinates from the mouse when dragging from a button in my window to outside that window.

Comment: There are no "events" in the Windows API at all. Can you provide more information about what you're trying to implement in your app, or what problem you're trying to solve? There are a couple of different possible solutions, and it's difficult to provide quality recommendations without some more detail.

Comment: Yes, I know they are called 'notifications'. Fixed it.

Comment: @Cody Sure that they are called notifications and not messages? But no matter how you call it, everybody knowing at least some small bits about WinAPI will understand what you're talking about. And yes, there are "events" in the WinAPI, but they mean something different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not as such, no. If you wanted to do something anywhere on the desktop from within your program, e.g. point somewhere or draw something anywhere, you could capture the mouse and then follow the movement until the mouse button is released. See [`SetCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262.aspx) for this.

For an example, see this article on MSDN: [Drawing Lines with the Mouse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645602.aspx#drawing_lines)

Otherwise you can always use [Windows hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959.aspx) to follow mouse movements anywhere.

Comment: `SetCapture` is a very good solution, depending on the exact problem to be solved. Remember to call [`ReleaseCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646261.aspx) when you're finished!

Comment: @Cody Gray: I think this is what I'm looking for. However I can't find a simple example for `SetCapture`. I edited my question to make it more clear what I want to do.

Comment: @Midas: indeed in such a case this is exactly the stuff you need. Check out `FindTool.c` from WinSpy++ on catch22.net for an example ...

Comment: @Midas: Yup, `SetCapture` is **exactly** what you need here. I use this to create a desktop "color picker" app, one of my favorite things to re-write in a new language. Its usage is fairly intuitive, and there's a sample on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645602.aspx#drawing_lines), linked from the documentation.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. I'm gonna accept this answer as soon as I got this working.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a [mouse hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wh_mouse_llhook) to be notified about all mouse events.

Comment: Remember that there's a performance penalty associated with low-level hooks. You should only install them when absolutely necessary, and remove them as soon as you are finished using them. They're a necessary solution sometimes, but still to be respected for the heavyweight that they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GetCursorPos, or GetMessagePos that contains coordinate of the last message